# What's a word for this phrase?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am writing a paragraph describing qualities of a successful manager.
I want to use a word (noun) for the "ability of not being stuck in the past/letting things go/moving ahead with no baggage from the past".

Do you know of a word that could be used in this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: The watchword of the ***pragmatist*** is *"We are where we are"* (so let's move forward from *here*, and not waste time thinking about where we could have been now if we'd done things differently in the past).

Comment: Innovative....?

Answer (score 1):

**"enterprising"** should fit.

> enterprising (adj) having or showing the ability or desire to do new and difficult things, marked by an independent energetic spirit and by readiness to act. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enterprising)
>
> enterprising (adj) ready to embark on new ventures; full of boldness and initiative. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enterprising)
>
> - "As an enterprising young reporter, she covered many important stories."
> - "The company is claiming that there will be huge financial rewards for enterprising sales representatives"

- "Young Jimmy has an enterprising spirit. He has just opened a lemonade stand."

Answer (score 1):

The adjective **proactive**.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proactive) says

> tending to initiate change rather than reacting to events

Answer (score 1):

Unencumbered:

Not having any burden or impediment.

Ex: he needed to travel light and unencumbered.
 http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unencumbered

Answer (score 0):

**Forward-thinking** - defined by Google as *favoring innovation and development; progressive.*